# using multer -s3 amazon server image upload error access denied

Tags: node.js, multer-s3

```
AccessDenied: Access Denied
    at Request.extractError (/home/cricket_game/node_modules/multer-s3/node_modules/s3fs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:524:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/home/cricket_game/node_modules/multer-s3/node_modules/s3fs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/home/cricket_game/node_modules/multer-s3/node_modules/s3fs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/home/cricket_game/node_modules/multer-s3/node_modules/s3fs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:615:14)
    at Request.transition (/home/cricket_game/node_modules/multer-s3/node_modules/s3fs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/cricket_game/node_modules/multer-s3/node_modules/s3fs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /home/cricket_game/node_modules/multer-s3/node_modules/s3fs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/cricket_game/node_modules/multer-s3/node_modules/s3fs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/cricket_game/node_modules/multer-s3/node_modules/s3fs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:617:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/home/cricket_game/node_modules/multer-s3/node_modules/s3fs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
    at Request.emit (/home/cricket_game/node_modules/multer-s3/node_modules/s3fs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/home/cricket_game/node_modules/multer-s3/node_modules/s3fs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:615:14)
    at Request.transition (/home/cricket_game/node_modules/multer-s3/node_modules/s3fs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/cricket_game/node_modules/multer-s3/node_modules/s3fs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /home/cricket_game/node_modules/multer-s3/node_modules/s3fs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/cricket_game/node_modules/multer-s3/node_modules/s3fs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
```

Comment: Can you give more details about this error? If you have already sorted this error can you share your solution with us ?

Comment: I solve this issue..i given full access to that upload folder on s3 amazon server.

Answer (score 5):

Even I was facing the same issue and I got it resolved.

For me the cause for this issue was I have been passing acl (Access control lists) key **acl: 'public-read'** to the multerS3 object params.

ACL key is case sensitive, instead of using **`acl: 'public-read'`** using **`ACL: 'public-read'`** worked fine.

Its ok if you didn't pass the ACL property in multerS3 object params.

If ACL not specified, then default is to store the file with **`ACL: 'private'`**

AWS supports the following options:

ACL: private | public-read | public-read-write | aws-exec-read | authenticated-read | bucket-owner-read | bucket-owner-full-control

multerS3 with **acl** (Access denied):

```
var upload = multer({
   storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        acl: 'public-read',
        bucket: BucketName,
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + '-' + file.originalname);
        }
    })
});
```

multerS3 with **ACL** (Works fine):

```
var upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        ACL: 'public-read',
        bucket: BucketName,
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + '-' + file.originalname);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> I solved this issue by going to my `S3` Account in `AWS` Website and give `full access` to the public under `Permissions` tab. (

By the way it's not recommended as AWS said but it's the only way I found so that I get it done)

Comment: Did you find a way doing it without turning off the public access blocks?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the following policy using IAM:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name-here/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your s3 bucket may not have public access. you can give your s3 bucket public access (not preferred) otherwise you can setup CloudFront distribution and provide necessary access to that distribution (preferred) [follow this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/getting-started/S3/).